# Java syntax error on token ";" expected

Tags: java, syntax, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a small problem in my java code. Error is

> Syntax error on token ";", , expected

Here is my code:

```
package natchly.chest;

import natchly.chest.blocks.BlockStoneChest;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.Init;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.network.NetworkMod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.LanguageRegistry;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid="chestsplus", name="Chests+", version="1.4.6_01")
@NetworkMod(clientSideRequired=true, serverSideRequired=false)
public class ModChests {

    public int idBlockStoneChest = 250;
    public static Block blockStoneChest; // <-------- Error here
    blockStoneChest = new BlockStoneChest(idBlockStoneChest).setBlockName("blockNAZWABLOKU").setHardness(1.5F).setResistance(5.0F);
    @Init
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent e) {
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(blockStoneChest);
        LanguageRegistry.addName(blockStoneChest, "Stone Chest");
    }

}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a syntax checking service.

Comment: But i think, it code is correct...

Comment: @user1798217  If the code was correct then why wyould there be a syntax error

Comment: The compiler and language disagree with your belief.

Answer (score 4):

Either do this:

```
public static Block blockStoneChest = new BlockStoneChest(idBlockStoneChest).setBlockName("blockNAZWABLOKU").setHardness(1.5F).setResistance(5.0F);
```

Or this:

```
public static Block blockStoneChest; <-------- Error here
static {
    blockStoneChest = new BlockStoneChest(idBlockStoneChest).setBlockName("blockNAZWABLOKU").setHardness(1.5F).setResistance(5.0F);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Combine these two lines into one declaration and instantiation step.  The way you're doing it isn't permitted in Java unless that's inside of a method.

```
public static BlockStoneChest blockStoneChest = new BlockStoneChest(idBlockStoneChest).setBlockName("blockNAZWABLOKU").setHardness(1.5F).setResistance(5.0F);
```